# How to use variable for server name in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two database servers, **server1** and **server2**, which are our diff environment of our legacy system. I have to write a stored procedure for getting data which is communicate with one of the env.

I want a way so that I can easily switch the env

Like:

```
Declare @Server nvarchar(20)
set @Server="server1"

select * 
from @Server.global.dbo.tblaccount
```

Answer (score 3):

Parameters cannot be used for identifiers -- column names, table names, schema names, server names, function names, and so on.

You can do this with dynamic SQL:

```
declare @Server nvarchar(20);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @Server = 'server1';

set @sql = 'select * from [Server].global.dbo.tblaccount';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[Server]', @Server);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

use [synonyms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx):

`create synonym mylocalschema.RemoteTable for server1.database.schema.table;`

to be referenced as:

`select top 10 * from mylocalschema.RemoteTable;`

depending on env the synonyms will be a reference to the right server and the code (sp, views, triggers, whatever) will be the very same for both.

the only duplicate item is the script to create synonyms: one for server1 and another copy for server2 (or maybe the same script built with dynamic sql...).